# How would I create a text-based board for a scrabble game in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-based

I am currently making a text-based scrabble game using python, and I was wondering how to make a board for such a game. Do I have to individually draw out each tile, or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array:

```
board = [4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5,
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5,
    0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5,
    1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 5,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5,
    4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5,
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
    1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 5,
    0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5,
    0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5,
    4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4] #This is the real board
```

To loop over it, use the following code. I use `termcolor.cprint()` to make the text different colors, matching the background color on a true scrabble board

```
for k in board:
    if k == 5:
        print'\n\n',
    elif k == 4:
        cprint(' TW', 'red', attrs=[], end = ' ')
    #print 'TW',
    elif k == 3:
        cprint(' DW', 'magenta', attrs=[], end = ' ')
    #print 'DW',
    elif k == 2:
        cprint(' TL', 'blue', attrs=[], end = ' ')
    #print 'TL',
    elif k == 1:
        cprint(' DL', 'cyan', attrs=[], end = ' ')
    #print 'DL',
    elif k == 0:
        print '___',
```

This prints:

[image: Scrabble Board]